# Installing liquibase on Windows and getting java errors

Tags: java, windows, installation, liquibase

So I've searched high and low with google, bing, duckduckgo, and stackoverflow and I can't seem to find an answer to my issue.

Installed jdk 8 64 bit windows (windows server 2012 AND Windows 10)

Installed Oracle instant client 12.2.0.1.0 64 bit windows

Installed Oracle SQL developer 18.2.0.183.1748 64 bit windows

Installed liquibase 3.6.2

Fixed system path variable so all these apps are in the Path
In a cmd window java returns the help information, liquibase returns:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at liquibase.logging.core.Slf4JLoggerFactory.getLog(Slf4JLoggerFactory.java:9)
        at liquibase.logging.LogService.getLog(LogService.java:39)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
```

What am I doing wrong? I get this error both on Windows 10 and windows server 2012.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

It appears that the liquibase 3.6.2 zip file (I downloaded `liquibase-3.6.2-bin.zip` from https://download.liquibase.org/download/?frm=n) does not contain the slf4j-api jar file, which is where the class in question is defined.

You should download `slf4j-1.7.25.zip` from https://www.slf4j.org/download.html, extract the files in that zip, and copy `slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar` into your liquibase\lib directory.

Comment: Even easier was copying the slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar file from the liquibase\sdk\lib-sdk directory to the liquibase\lib directory